# Hyphen in "Samstagen, Sonn- und Feiertagen"

Tags: spelling

I saw this in an official poster:

> ...in den Nächten vor Samstagen, Sonn- und Feiertagen.

Is there any reason behind this not have been written as follows?

> ... in den Nächten vor Sams-, Sonn- und Feiertagen.

Does the **s** of *Samstag* mess this second variant up?

---

By the way, [Vienna](http://www.wienerlinien.at/) is were I saw it:

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: *Samstag* is elsewhere called *Sonnabend*, the phrase might have been "localized" after copying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It actually feels equally weird to think of

> Mon- bis Freitag

I can’t remember ever seeing that construction, it is usually

> Montag bis Freitag

Although that has more characters. This leads me to suspect that the weekdays are hardly thought of as compound words and thus cannot be used as such by separating away the *-tag* part.

On the other hand, *Sonn- und Feiertage* is a very fixed expression, because — as Stephie noted — they are treated equally by German law and historically by the churches (save certain solemnities that are even more important). Whatever commandments the church placed onto believers to be followed on holy days, it would always be *an Sonn- und Feiertagen*. That would provide a valid reason for a fixed expression entering the language where separating away the *-tag* is not as accepted for all other combinations.

Comment: I can only speak for Austria, but constructions like _Sam-, Sonn- und Feiertag_ are not unheard of (or unseen, for that matter). Personally I wouldn't use it, but a quick Google search shows that many people do.  https://www.google.at/search?q=sam-+sonn-+und+feiertagen&oq=sam-+sonn-+und+feiertagen&aqs=chrome..69i57.7790j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22sam-+sonn-+und+feiertage

Comment: @Ingmar That may be a good basis for an answer saying it’s possible in Austria ;)

Comment: @Ingmar Wiener Linien (wie ich nachträglich die Frage vervollständigt habe) stimmt dir zu...

Answer (score 7):

Good observation - I can not remember any counter-example. But the separation between (Saturday) and (Sundays and holidays) has probably legal reasons, not grammatical reasons.

By German law, a Saturday is a "[Werktag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werktag)"<sup>1</sup> as opposed to Sundays and legal holidays that have a special "protected" legal status.

So from that perspective it makes sense to separate Saturdays from Sundays and holidays - and hyphenate accordingly. And yes, "[Sams](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sams_(Buchreihe))-" sounds weird. More like the character in a childrens book by Paul Maar.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with "[Arbeitstag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Arbeitstag)", which for most professions is Mo.-Fr., but may be different. My hairdresser works Tu.-Sa., for a nurse a Sunday may be an Arbeitstag.

Answer (score 2):

Ich meine Jan kommt der Erklärung nahe, um dann bei Sonn- und Feiertagen den Punkt zu verpassen und eine unsprachliche Erklärung in Rechtsfragen zu suchen.

Dass Mon- bis Freitag nicht geht hat m.E. den Grund darin, dass *Mon* kein erkennbarer Wortstamm von irgendwas ist, so wie *Sams*, und deshalb nicht alleinstehen kann.

Fuß- und Handball, Hard- und Software, Kopf- und Gliederschmerzen, Luft- und Raumfahrt - soweit ich weiß gibt es überall einen erkennbaren Wortstamm, wenn Kompositionen getrennt werden. Im *Sonn* des Sonn- und Feiertags ist die Sonne aber leicht zu erkennen, deswegen geht es da.

Comment: Diese gefällt mir. Trotzem kann ich nicht aufhören, den Mond an *Montag* zu erkennen.

Comment: *Donner- und Freitag*?

Comment: _Hol-/Holl-/Holt-/Holz- und Deutschland_? _Erd-, Him-, Brom- und Blaubeeren_?

Comment: @Crissov: Was willst Du damit sagen?

Comment: @Jan: Heißt der Tag nicht Donnerstag?

Comment: Ingmar hat in einem anderen Kommentar auch von *Sam-, Sonn- und Feiertagen* gesprochen …

Comment: Die Wurzel von _Holland_, nämlich _holt_ ‚Holz, Wald’, ist ähnlich intransparent wie _Mon(d)-, Dien(s)-_ oder _Sam(s)-_ sowie _Him-_; _Brom-_ hingegen ist irreführend wie _Donner(s)-_ und _Frei-_. _Deutsch-, Erd(e)-, Blau-_ und _Sonn(e)-_ sind hingegen recht transparent. Die Frage ist, ob deine These, dass gebundene unikale Morpheme in Komposita nicht aufgelöst werden, wirklich haltbar ist. Ich weiß es nicht, daher keine Antwort sondern nur Kommentar als Denkanstoß.

Comment: @Crissov: Him-, Brom- und Blaubeere klingt mir mehr nach Heinz-Erhardschem Wortspiel als nach gängigem Sprachgebrauch, ähnlich Holl- und Deutschland (Quelle?), aber ich sitze zwischen 2 Stühlen, der zweite ist, die Antwort zu löschen.

Answer (score 0):

"Sonn- und Feiertage" is an *idiomatic phrase* for non-working days. As with most idiomatic phrases, it sounds strange and unfamilar when expanded.

Comment: While that's true, I think the point was the contraction of Samstag, not the expansion of *Sonntag*. Btw. there is a downvote, and it's *not* from me.

Comment: With "expansion" I meant the inclusion of Samstag into the phrase.